# `tsc -b foo bar --watch` only builds foo, but not bar

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am having a TypeScript package (using yarn 2 as package manager) with two different source trees:

```
|- src-bin
\- src
```

The sources in `src-bin` target node, whereas the sources in `src` target a browser environment. Hence, I am having two different `tsconfig.json` files.

I usually build them with `tsc -b . src-bin`, which works quite fine.

However, in "watch-mode", `tsc` only compile and watches `src`, but not `src-bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve it using project references:

The `tsconfig.json` (for src):

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "references": [{ "path": "src-bin" }],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

The `src-bin/tsconfig.json` (for src-bin):

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../build/bin",
    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

Running `tsc -b --watch` now compiles BOTH source trees.